# Как разбить строку на слова и получить массив слов Python?

Tags: python, массивы

Нужно разбить фразу по словам и получить массив, в котором каждое слово - элемент массива

```html
<h1>Исходная фраза</h1>
<p>Cat dog house</p>

<h1>Полученный массив</h1>
<p>['cat', 'dog', 'house']</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "Cat dog house"
lst = s.split()
print(lst)
```

Неужели это не ищется поиском здесь или не гуглится??